# Is there a better way to count seconds in python

Tags: python

```
def stopWatchSeconds(secondCnt) :
    """ counts second for secondCnt seconds """

    # is there a better way to do this?
    startTime = time.clock()
    ellapsed = 0
    for x in range(0, secondCnt, 1) :
        print "loop cycle time: %f, seconds cnt: %02d" % (ellapsed , x)    
        ellapsed = 1 - (time.clock() - startTime)
        time.sleep(ellapsed)
        startTime = time.clock()
```

I'm reviewing some source code for a buddy of mine and came across this function. I am very new to Python so it is more of a learning experience for me. I see that he put in a comment about is there a better way to do this. I started thinking about it, and I know how I would do it in C#, but since python is so much more laxed it does seem like this function could be improved.

Comment: Could you give a little bit more info about the goal of this function?  Is it for benchmarking, a timer, etc? Different goals might make different methods more appropriate.  Also, time.clock() behaves differently on *nix systems vs Windows systems.  What is the target platform?

Comment: Well the the program is to test a port by sending data for x amount of seconds on a Android device.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approach to me (as a nitpick, elapsed should only have one 'l').  You might also be able to use the Python timeit module which has a default_timer that tracks wall clock time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure this code does what you think it does, at least on a *nix OS. [According to the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html#time.clock), `time.clock()` returns *processor time*, which basically means that any time spent in `time.sleep()` is not counted. However, on Windows, `time.clock()` returns the actual time since it was first called.

A better way to determine the time since the function was first called is to use `time.time()`, which returns the number of seconds since the *epoch*. We can still use `time.clock()` to determine the process time if we are using a *nix OS. (If you are using Windows, you may want to upgrade to Python 3.3 which introduces the platform independent function `time.process_time()`. (There may be another way to do it if you are using 2.x, but I don't know what it is.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

def stopwatch(seconds):
    start = time.time()
    # time.time() returns the number of seconds since the unix epoch.
    # To find the time since the start of the function, we get the start
    # value, then subtract the start from all following values.
    time.clock()    
    # When you first call time.clock(), it just starts measuring
    # process time. There is no point assigning it to a variable, or
    # subtracting the first value of time.clock() from anything.
    # Read the documentation for more details.
    elapsed = 0
    while elapsed < seconds:
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        print "loop cycle time: %f, seconds count: %02d" % (time.clock() , elapsed) 
        time.sleep(1)  
        # You were sleeping in your original code, so I've stuck this in here...
        # You'll notice that the process time is almost nothing.
        # This is because we are spending most of the time sleeping,
        # which doesn't count as process time.
        # For funsies, try removing "time.sleep()", and see what happens.
        # It should still run for the correct number of seconds,
        # but it will run a lot more times, and the process time will
        # ultimately be a lot more. 
        # On my machine, it ran the loop 2605326 times in 20 seconds.
        # Obviously it won't run it more than 20 times if you use time.sleep(1)

stopwatch(20)
```

If you find the comments more confusing than helpful, here's a non-commented version...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

def stopwatch(seconds):
    start = time.time()
    time.clock()    
    elapsed = 0
    while elapsed < seconds:
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        print "loop cycle time: %f, seconds count: %02d" % (time.clock() , elapsed) 
        time.sleep(1)  

stopwatch(20)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the "processor time" distinction!  I was wondering why time.clock() was reporting sub-second times around a 15-second HTTP request.